# Wordpress new user / forgot password emails are broken

Tags: php, wp-mail

I have no idea why it does this - I checked my mu-plugins, functions.php, there's currently nothing that alters emails.

(Note that I translated these by heart, words might not be the same but links matter)

If user registers, he/she recieves:

> Username: Tomato To assing a new password, visit:
>   https://www.my-site.com/wp-login.php

This is very very wrong url, isn't it? There should be keys and all sort of strings, right? Actually, this is not "change password" url at all - that's just login url that get's included one way or another. "Change password" url is missing.

WP generates url like this in `pluggable.php` in /includes folder:

```
$message .= '<' . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user->user_login), 'login') . ">\r\n\r\n";
```

---

Another things is "Forgot password" email:

> Someone has requested password change on site: http://www.my-site.com/
>   Username: Tomato If that's not true, ignore the message and nothing happens. To change the password, visit:

There's also no url.

It should generate the url roughly in same way as in first case.

---

I've tried it with different email providers. **What could be the problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make a plugin, copy-paste whole fuction from pluggable.php that makes new account and sends the email only to change `< >` to `( )` or remove `< >` which wraps the URL.

It breaks because WordPress email was `HTML` by default (**it should be text**) and `< >` are read as `HTML` tags. I didn't set emails to `HTML`, Im not sure why it was `HTML` by default.

Fortunately it's not a big deal for me because I was going to overwrite this function in future one way or another in order to make beautiful and responsive `HTML` emails.

This is very weird, is anyone else having this issue?